# How to have multiple rewriterules with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to build a multilingual website with Drupal.

I like to have the following url format

`http://domain/[language]/[node id]`

so I added the following rule to .htaccess for testing purpose

`RewriteRule ^jpn/[0-9]$ jpn.html`

The problem is that the rule is overwritten by the following rule

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]`

How do I have multiple rewrite rules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second `RewriteRule` has the [`L Flag`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) set, which means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.

If you want your first rule to also stop any further processing, add the L Flag to it as well.

```
RewriteRule ^jpn/[0-9]$ jpn.html [L]
```

Also make sure that your second rule is listed last, because it matches everything (.*) and thus, Apache will never see any other rule after it.

Edited: the L Flag URL

Comment: // Thank you!! it works perfectly. Where can I get list of those...[L] ? what is name of it?

Comment: Check the link (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) - all flags are explained right there. L stands for Last.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this [L] really works in each case to avoid overwrite one each other. I'm not an expert on this, but i spent a day to figure out that you just need to add 1 Atome to a RewriteRule  that did worked before without beeing overwriten, and it starts to get overwriten again from the first one. It's hard for me to believe that 2 different Rules, in 1 htaccess can properly work for 2 differents files.

Both Worked 100% well

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)\.htm$ display.php?$1&category=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)\.htm$  news.php?$1 [L]
```

displ

news

Link 2 displays the result of link1 instead..., just tell me why?

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)\.htm$ display.php?$1&category=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)\.htm$ news.php?$1&obj=$2&search=$3 [L]
```

displ

news